# Include Facets under the root element of the enunciate.xml does not work in enunciation in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, rest

I am working with enunciation for the API documentation. I have added Facets to my API to include it in documentation.
But when I include Facets under the root element of enunciate.xml by

```
    <facets>
        <!-- include all components with the facet applied. -->
        <include name="Admin"/>
    </facets>
```

It doesn't include the API with Admin Facet name. While exclude `<exclude name="Admin"/>`  excludes all the API with Admin Facet.

How can we just include the API with Admin facet and exclude other?